# footer is too big and i want sections side by side

Tags: html, css, footer

footer doesnt seem good how can i fix it?

it looks huge plus i want to put kategoriler and referanslar section side by side.

i tried to make footer smaller and i tried to put sections together but i couldnt

```css
.site-footer {
  background-color: rgb(226, 109, 128);
  padding: 45px 0 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.site-footer hr {
  border-top-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  opacity: 0.5
}

.site-footer hr.small {
  margin: 20px 0
}

.site-footer h6 {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 2px
}

.site-footer a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.site-footer a:hover {
  color: #eeafdd;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-links {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none
}

.footer-links li {
  display: block
}

.footer-links a {
  color: #ffffff
}

.footer-links a:active,
.footer-links a:focus,
.footer-links a:hover {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-links.inline li {
  display: inline-block
}

.site-footer .social-icons {
  text-align: right
}

.site-footer .social-icons a {
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-left: 6px;
  margin-right: 0;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #33353d
}

.copyright-text {
  margin: 0
}

@media (max-width:991px) {
  .site-footer [class^=col-] {
    margin-bottom: 30px
  }
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
  .site-footer {
    padding-bottom: 0
  }
  .site-footer .copyright-text,
  .site-footer .social-icons {
    text-align: center
  }
}

.social-icons {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none
}

.social-icons li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 4px
}

.social-icons li.title {
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #96a2b2;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 13px
}

.social-icons a {
  background-color: #eceeef;
  color: #818a91;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 44px;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 8px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
  -o-transition: all .2s linear;
  transition: all .2s linear
}

.social-icons a:active,
.social-icons a:focus,
.social-icons a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #060708
}

.social-icons.size-sm a {
  line-height: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  width: 34px;
  font-size: 14px
}

.social-icons a.facebook:hover {
  background-color: #ff0606
}

.social-icons a.twitter:hover {
  background-color: #00aced
}

.social-icons a.linkedin:hover {
  background-color: #0f86fd
}

.social-icons a.dribbble:hover {
  background-color: #e86969
}

@media (max-width:7px) {
  .social-icons li.title {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 0;
    font-weight: 600
  }
}
```

```html
<footer class="site-footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">


      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
        <h6>Kategoriler</h6>
        <ul class="footer-links">
          <li><a href="index.html">Anasayfa</a></li>
          <li><a href="hakkımda.html">Hakkımda</a></li>
          <li><a href="fotogaleri.html">Fotogaleri</a></li>
          <li><a href="iletisim.html">İletişim</a></li>

          <li><a href="http://scanfcode.com/category/android/">Android</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://scanfcode.com/category/templates/">Templates</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
        <h6>Referans Linkleri</h6>
        <ul class="footer-links">
          <li><a href="https://www.adu.edu.tr/">Adnan Menderes Üniversitesi</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://scanfcode.com/contact/">Damla Zeliha İnce</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://hakanguleryuz.com.tr/">Hakan Güleryüz</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://scanfcode.com/privacy-policy/">Privacy Policy</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://scanfcode.com/sitemap/">Sitemap</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <p class="copyright-text">Copyright &copy; 2022 All Rights Reserved by
          <a href="#">Buse Nur Çetin</a>.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <ul class="social-icons">
          <li><a class="Github" href="https://github.com/busenurcetin"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a></li>
          <li><a class="twitter" href="https://twitter.com/busenurcetin16"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
          <li><a class="dribbble" href="https://realbusenurcetin.tech/"><i class="fab fa-safari"></i></a></li>
          <li><a class="linkedin" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/busenur-%C3%A7etin-349b05253/"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.site-footer
{
  background-color: rgb(226, 109, 128);
  padding:45px 0 20px;
  font-size:15px;
  line-height:24px;
  color:#ffffff;
}
.site-footer hr
{
  border-top-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
  opacity:0.5
}
.site-footer hr.small
{
  margin:20px 0
}
.site-footer h6
{
  color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-size:16px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  margin-top:5px;
  letter-spacing:2px
}
.site-footer a
{
  color:#ffffff;
}
.site-footer a:hover
{
  color:#eeafdd;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.footer-links
{
  padding-left:0;
  list-style:none
  
}
.footer-links li
{
  display:block
}
.footer-links a
{
  color:#ffffff
}
.footer-links a:active,.footer-links a:focus,.footer-links a:hover
{
  color:#000000;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.footer-links.inline li
{
  display:inline-block
}
.site-footer .social-icons
{
  text-align:right
}
.site-footer .social-icons a
{
  width:50px;
  height:40px;
  line-height:40px;
  margin-left:6px;
  margin-right:0;
  border-radius:100%;
  background-color:#33353d
}
.copyright-text
{
  margin:0
}
@media (max-width:991px)
{
  .site-footer [class^=col-]
  {
    margin-bottom:30px
  }
}
@media (max-width:767px)
{
  .site-footer
  {
    padding-bottom:0
  }
  .site-footer .copyright-text,.site-footer .social-icons
  {
    text-align:center
  }
}
.social-icons
{
  padding-left:0;
  margin-bottom:0;
  list-style:none
}
.social-icons li
{
  display:inline-block;
  margin-bottom:4px
}
.social-icons li.title
{
  margin-right:15px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color:#96a2b2;
  font-weight:700;
  font-size:13px
}
.social-icons a{
  background-color:#eceeef;
  color:#818a91;
  font-size:16px;
  display:inline-block;
  line-height:44px;
  width:44px;
  height:44px;
  text-align:center;
  margin-right:8px;
  border-radius:100%;
  -webkit-transition:all .2s linear;
  -o-transition:all .2s linear;
  transition:all .2s linear
}
.social-icons a:active,.social-icons a:focus,.social-icons a:hover
{
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#060708
}
.social-icons.size-sm a
{
  line-height:34px;
  height:34px;
  width:34px;
  font-size:14px
}
.social-icons a.facebook:hover
{
  background-color:#ff0606
}
.social-icons a.twitter:hover
{
  background-color:#00aced
}
.social-icons a.linkedin:hover
{
  background-color:#0f86fd
}
.social-icons a.dribbble:hover
{
  background-color:#e86969
}
.row{
  display:flex;
}
.marginright{
  margin-right:10px;
}
.marginleft{
  margin-left:10px;
}
@media (max-width:7px)
{
  .social-icons li.title
  {
    display:block;
    margin-right:0;
    font-weight:600
  }
}
```

```html
<footer class="site-footer">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            
  
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 marginleft marginright" >
              <h6>Kategoriler</h6>
              <ul class="footer-links">
                <li><a href="index.html">Anasayfa</a></li>
                <li><a href="hakkımda.html">Hakkımda</a></li>
                <li><a href="fotogaleri.html">Fotogaleri</a></li>
                <li><a href="iletisim.html">İletişim</a></li>
                
                <li><a href="http://scanfcode.com/category/android/">Android</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://scanfcode.com/category/templates/">Templates</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
  
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
              <h6>Referans Linkleri</h6>
              <ul class="footer-links">
                <li><a href="https://www.adu.edu.tr/">Adnan Menderes Üniversitesi</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://scanfcode.com/contact/">Damla Zeliha İnce</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://hakanguleryuz.com.tr/">Hakan Güleryüz</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://scanfcode.com/privacy-policy/">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://scanfcode.com/sitemap/">Sitemap</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <p class="copyright-text">Copyright &copy; 2022 All Rights Reserved by 
           <a href="#">Buse Nur Çetin</a>.
              </p>
            </div>
  
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <ul class="social-icons">
                <li><a class="Github" href="https://github.com/busenurcetin"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a></li>
                <li><a class="twitter" href="https://twitter.com/busenurcetin16"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                <li><a class="dribbble" href="https://realbusenurcetin.tech/"><i class="fab fa-safari"></i></a></li>
                <li><a class="linkedin" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/busenur-%C3%A7etin-349b05253/"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>   
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
  </footer>
```

Comment: Please explain what you changed/added and why so people can understand what's happening